# Copying base data sheet along with selected sheets from source workbook to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking at building a master workbook which receives a monthly dump of data for all Cost Centres which will then populate a large number of worksheets within the workbook, and which then need to be split off and sent out to service heads. A service head will receive a selection of worksheets based on the first 4 characters of the sheet name (although this may change in due course).

eg 1234x, 1234y, 5678a, 5678b will produce two new workbooks named 1234 and 5678 with two sheets in each.

I have cobbled some code from various forum to create a macro that will work through a hard coded array defining the service head 4 character codes and create a series of new workbooks. And which seems to work.

However.. I also need to include the main data dump sheet within the source file (called "data") with the the array of files being copied over so that the links remain with the data sheet being copied over. If I write a line to copy over the data sheet separately, the new workbook still refers back to the source file, which service heads do not have access to.

So main question is: how can I add the "data" tab into the Sheets(CopyNames).Copy code so it is copied over with all the other files in the array at the same to keep the links intact?

Second question is if I decide it is the first two characters of the worksheet define the sheets that relate to a service head, how do I tweak the split/mid line of code - I've trialled around but am getting tied up in knots!

Any other tips to make the code more elegant much appreciated (there may be quite a long list of service head codes and I am sure there is a better way of creating a list for the routine to loop through)

```
    Sub Copy_Sheets()
  Dim strNames As String, strWSName As String
  Dim arrNames, CopyNames
  Dim wbAct As Workbook
  Dim i As Long
  Dim arrlist As Object

  Set arrlist = CreateObject("system.collections.arraylist")
  arrlist.Add "1234"
  arrlist.Add "5678"


  Set wbAct = ActiveWorkbook
  For Each Item In arrlist

  For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    strNames = strNames & "," & Sheets(i).Name
  Next i
    arrNames = Split(Mid(strNames, 2), ",")

    'strWSName =("1234")
    strWSName = Item

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        CopyNames = Filter(arrNames, strWSName, True, vbTextCompare)
        If UBound(CopyNames) > -1 Then
          Sheets(CopyNames).Copy
          ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strWSName & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
          ActiveWorkbook.Close
          wbAct.Activate
        Else
          MsgBox "No sheets found: " & strWSName
        End If

    Next Item

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you not change at this point  strNames = strNames & "," & LEFT(Sheets(i).NameSheets(i).Name,2)  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheets()

With ThisWorkbook

    Dim SheetIndex As Long
    Dim ValidSheetNames() As String
    ReDim ValidSheetNames(1 To .Worksheets.Count)

    ' Build a 1 dimensional array called ValidSheetNames, which contains every sheet in the master workbook other than DEDICATEDSHEET. '
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In .Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "DEDICATEDSHEET" Then
            SheetIndex = SheetIndex + 1
            ValidSheetNames(SheetIndex) = ws.Name
        End If
    Next ws
    ReDim Preserve ValidSheetNames(1 To SheetIndex)

    ' Read all ServiceCodes into a 1-dimensional array '
    Dim ServiceHeadCodes As Variant
    ServiceHeadCodes = Application.Transpose(.Worksheets("DEDICATEDSHEET").Range("CCLIST[CC]").Value2)

    Dim CodeIndex As Long

    ' Now loop through each ServiceHeadCode '
    For CodeIndex = LBound(ServiceHeadCodes) To UBound(ServiceHeadCodes)

        ' Put all sheet names which contain the current ServiceHeadCode into an array called SheetsToCopy '
        Dim SheetsToCopy() As String
        SheetsToCopy = Filter(ValidSheetNames, ServiceHeadCodes(CodeIndex), True, vbTextCompare)

        ' Check if SheetToCopy now contains any sheet names at all. '
        If UBound(SheetsToCopy) > -1 Then

            ' Add the name of the Data sheet to the end of the array '
            ReDim Preserve SheetsToCopy(LBound(SheetsToCopy) To (UBound(SheetsToCopy) + 1))
            SheetsToCopy(UBound(SheetsToCopy)) = "Data"


            Dim OutputWorkbook As Workbook
            Set OutputWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Add

            ' Copy all sheets which are in SheetToCopy array to newly created OutputWorkbook '
            .Worksheets(SheetsToCopy).Copy OutputWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

            ' Delete the default Sheet1, which should be at the end as copied sheets were inserted before it. '
            ' But suppress the Are you sure you want to delete this sheet.. message. '
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            OutputWorkbook.Worksheets(OutputWorkbook.Worksheets.Count).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            ' Re-enable alerts, as we want to see any other dialogue boxes/messages

            ' Not providing a full directory path below means OutputWorkbook will be saved wherever Thisworkbook is saved.'
            OutputWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ServiceHeadCodes(CodeIndex) & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
            OutputWorkbook.Close
        Else
            MsgBox "No sheets found: " & ServiceHeadCodes(CodeIndex)
        End If

    Next CodeIndex

End With

End Sub
```

Untested and written on mobile, sorry for bad formatting.

This approach proposes that you store all service head codes in a 1-column Excel table on a dedicated sheet that is referred to via Excel table nomenclature (which might be easier than ArrayList.Add for each new service head code).

I assume code is stored in master workbook ('thisworkbook'), which might not be true.

You could modify the serviceheadcodes table directly on the spreadsheet itself, if you later decide that SheetsToCopy will be determined by first 2, 3 or X characters -- or you could modify array itself with left$() function.

Hope it works or gives you some ideas.

**Edit:** This is my sheet and table layout (which I assume matches yours).

[image: Sheet and table structure]

And this is what the code above gives me on my computer.

[image: Output files]

Comment: Thanks Chillin, I will give your code a test this week although I suspect that because the copy operation is not done in one go it will affect the way the links work. Doing it manually only worked (i.e. links stayed within the new workbook) when I selected the sheets to copy over with the "data" sheet at the same time.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that copy-pasting sheets in one go would eliminate external/source workbook references. Learn something new everyday I guess. If the code as it is doesn't do what you want, there is always the option to create another array, which holds SheetsToCopy plus "Data", and then pass this new array to .worksheets(newarray).copy outputworkbook.worksheets(0). Anyway, see how it goes.

Comment: I've loaded your code into a test wb and it's stopping at SheetNames(SheetIndex) = .Worksheets(SheetIndex) with message 'subscript out of range'. Also changed the line  ServiceHeadCodes = Application.Transpose(.Worksheets("DEDICATEDSHEET").Range("CCLIST[CC]").Value2) to match Table name and col header.

Comment: I forgot to access the .name property in the loop. I've edited that line in my post now.

Comment: The SheetNames array is 0-based. As far as I know, the worksheets collection index is also 0-based. If the code still doesn't work, we can just use a simpler, safer for-each loop -- which is arguably what I should have been doing.

Comment: The line SheetNames(SheetIndex) = .Worksheets(SheetIndex).Name is still coming up with "subscript out of range" error

Comment: I've just checked. Worksheets are 1-based, not 0-based.

Something else that I've noticed is that the initial ServiceHeaderCodes array may not be 1-dimensional.

Comment: It's getting there :)  I've just set two CC codes in the DEDICATED test sheet and its working for the first one and linking correctly to "data" sheet but it's getting stuck on the second run on    If UBound(SheetsToCopy) > -1 Then   with a 'subscript out of range error'

Comment: FYI just in case I've done something wrong here - I have replaced your code with ServiceHeadCodes = Application.Transpose(.Worksheets("DEDICATEDSHEET").Range("CCLIST[CC]").Value2) where CCLIST is the Table with the codes in and picks up the range of codes only (no header) and CC is the column header in the CCLIST Table. (& I don't understand the Value.2 command).

Comment: Have taken your latest code in full and it's still getting stuck on the same line If UBound(SheetsToCopy) > -1 Then  the second time around, first loop creates the new workbook as intended. Same error message "subscript out of range".

Comment: Strange, I tested the code on my end with a sample workbook. I encountered no errors and the output .xlsx files were created. What version of Microsoft Office are you running? Any chance you could share your workbook with me? At the very least I would recommend restarting the computer and then re-running the code.

Comment: Hi, I use Excel for Mac 2011 v.14.5.1. I'll try it on a machine with Windows Office.

Comment: It was the Mac - sorry  - should have thought about mentioning that at the start. Works perfectly on Windows Office. Not the first time Mac has tripped me up. Thank you so much. This is a powerful bit of code which can really help with what is currently a very clunky process. Before we close the thread, can you tell me how I would alter the code to select and group the worksheets on first two characters rather than first 4?

Comment: Just looked up the filter function and answered my own question!  I can enter any number of characters to define the service head i.e. sheet grouping as the filter function looks at comparing and matching the defined characters within the strings (sheet names) in the array. Thanks again. This thread is a little rambly (my fault entirely!) Does it all need deleting so others can just focus on your elegant code? Hard to believe you did most of it on a phone!!

Comment: If you want to switch freely and flexibly between 2 and 4 characters, add a second column to the table CCLIST (can be done by typing the new column's header immediately next to the last column's header of the existing table, Excel will do the rest). In the second column's first cell, enter the formula =left([@CC],2), drag it down for all table rows. This second column should now be a calculated column (meaning if you add new ServiceHeadCodes in the first column CC or new rows, the first 2 characters should automatically be returned in the second column).

Comment: Then prior to running the code, change "CCLIST[CC]" to "CCLIST[SECONDCOLUMNNAME]" in the line: ServiceHeadCodes = Application.Transpose(.Worksheets("DEDICATEDSHEET").Range("CCLIST[CC]").Value2) and SECONDCOLUMNNAME is whatever the second column's header is in your workbook. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Just noticed your last comment. I wouldn't worry about the rambling. It happens and comments get auto-deleted after a certain time period (I think). If you're happy with the provided solution, maybe mark the question as solved. Also, I think using Application.ScreenUpdating = false before the loop and Application.ScreenUpdating = true after the loop may speed things up if you have a lot of service head codes.

Comment: Will do. I've got lots of little bits of code I can add that will make it more user friendly but you have sorted out the heavy lifting. Much obliged.